# Execute group of promises or cancel them all

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, promise, es6-promise

My question is how we grauntee the exection of group of promises in JavaScript?
I have 3 promises, one for deleting user profile picture, one for deleting user cover image and last one for deleting the user object and his information.

What I need to handle, that if one promise is rejected, I should cancel excetion of the others.
As it won't be logic to delete, for example, the user image however, his info didn't be deleted.

Any suggestions?

Comment: It seems best to decide on an order of operation if one process is reliant on success of the others (especially in the case of deletion). You can then simply wrap the successive calls in a `try ... catch`. Otherwise [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) will reject if any of the passed promises reject, but any promises before the rejection will have resolved which seems not ideal in the case of deletion.

Comment: A promise cannot be "cancelled". You can at best cancel the underlying operation - but even that may or may not work in time. What you actually want here is a **transaction** in a database that supports them.

Answer (score 1):

#### There is no automatic method of doing this

This is something that would have to be done at server level. It is called making the operation "atomic".

Presumably you are currently send out the deletion requests without waiting for each to return before sending the next?

Unless the server specifically provides a way to do atomic operations, i.e. "Do all 3 or none of them", with your current workflow you cannot achieve what you are asking for.

#### Workaround for most uses

Assuming you have no control over the server, and can only call each promise in turn, I suggest this:

- Call the User Object deletion
- If successful, call the User Profile picture deletion
- If successful, call the user cover image

Once the user object is deleted, they won't be able to get into the system and therefore (presumably) it is not a disaster for you that the images are still present.

Thus, if the image deletions fail, the user still has the experience that they intended: they can no longer log in.

#### Workaround if you legally must delete the images

In this situation, do the deletions the other way round. In other words, if the image deletions fail, the user will not be deleted. Or the images may be deleted, but the user not be deleted.

Presumably you could tell the user that the deletion was incomplete and to try again. The next time might be successful.